# Property 'x' does not exist when defining two return types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Take the following example:

```js
interface Dog {
  name: string
}

const likeDog = true

const getDog = (): Dog | boolean => {
  const val = likeDog ? { name: 'fido' } : false
  return val
}

const myComponent = (): void => {
  const dog = getDog()
  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'boolean | Dog'.
  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'false'
  console.log(dog.name) // <-- What is the proper way to deal with this?
}
```

What is the proper way to deal with the compiler errors listed above `console.log(dog.name)`? Or is this typescript tell you to rethink how you are architecting your app?

Is see this as fairly common situation. Take React hooks for instance:

```js
interface Dog {
  name: string
}

const myComponent = () => {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState<Dog | boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    // I make a fetch request
    fetchDog().then(dog => setDog(dog))
  }, [])

  if (!dog) {
    return;
  }

  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'boolean | Dog'.
  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'false'
  return <div>{dog.name}</div>
}
```

Same compiler error. In this situation, `dog` should be false for the early return but then after the `getDog()` resolves, we set the response and render. I understand you *could* do `const [dog, setDog] = useState<Dog>()` and the `if (dog)` would still evaluate to falsely but this seems *less* explicit.

Comment: The second snippet looks perfectly reasonable to me. Is there something that feels ugly about it to you?

Comment: Agreed with above. You could also do `console.log(dog?.name ?? false)`

Comment: It doesn't feel ugly to me either but `<div>{dog.name}</div>`gives me the same compile error as the snippet above. 
`  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'boolean | Dog'` and 
 ` // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'false'``

Comment: Can you provide a link to a web IDE that shows this error?  Right now [I cannot reproduce it](https://tsplay.dev/gWodew).  What am I missing?

Comment: Ahhh! Ok, I actually had boolean where false is now. :/ https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFICiAZvUhnAL5z1QQhwDkUqDLwBQw4ADtKUeuiRwAIhADmuYXDjiUIJAC44hGFAlLhrYQBNmAGxQCO+cRmARxHJDDQALRUoAUASj0ABS4QYGIAHh8APgBuUTQXAzgQAE8AYW5IcSRJOABeOACC6NV1RPFkgG1zZWxiGB8AXQKCYjIKJCjlOAAfOAAjCAgrVHFo3xkrYn9RdRoGJgxfYvzSnDV1OAB6bbgASRSUAGs5FDcPTzgBAEd8JANN9SZLnwCAOhhPXN9alTX9O43n9-LN1KxsFUmrNNsB6EUAIQgspbAQwfBQcTxcFza7uDGuCLmYAAN2iOD+7002lYEW2xLJpiAA

You are correct good sir!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<Dog | boolean>` the correct type here would be `<Dog | false>`

```
interface Dog {
  name: string
}

const myComponent = () => {
  const [dog, setDog] = useState<Dog | false>(false) // <-- updated 

  useEffect(() => {
    // I make a fetch request
    fetchDog().then(dog => setDog(dog))
  }, [])

  if (!dog) {
    return;
  }

  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'boolean | Dog'.
  // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'false'
  return <div>{dog.name}</div>
}
```